# Use change in overall rate to affect baseline risk profile

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I asked the following question in CrossValidated, but I'm wondering if it is better suited to this platform...

If there are daily unconditional probabilities of an event that result in a weekly occurrence of an event of 25%, like so:

```
Day    Prob
1      0.04026439
2      0.04026439
3      0.04026439
4      0.04026439
5      0.04026439
6      0.04026439
7      0.04026439
```

And I want to change these probabilities so they result in a weekly occurrence of 30% instead, I can use the formula:

$ P = 1 - (1 - rate)^{1/7} $

where rate is now 0.3.

However, what if the probabilities are not equal on all the days - for example, if there is a higher probability of the event occurring earlier in the week, like this:

```
Day    Prob
1      0.0496772
2      0.04584501
3      0.04210299
4      0.04026439
5      0.03844668
6      0.03487194
7      0.03137491
```

The overall occurrence here is still 25%. But what if I want to modify these baseline probabilities so to reflect a given change in the weekly occurrence. What I want to do is to increase the daily baseline probabilities proportionally, so the shape of the baseline risk profile doesn't change but the overall occurrence does change - say from 25% to 30%.

Is it even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "increase the daily baseline probabilities equally," in what sense do you mean "equally?"  I presume that what you actually mean is *proportionally*, i.e., if $p_i$ is the event probability on day $i$ of the week, $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, 7\}$, then you want to determine a constant $k$ such that $k p_i$ represents the updated probability on day $i$.  In such a case, then what you can see is that the weekly event probability is $$1 - \prod_{i=1}^7 (1 - p_i) = 0.25,$$ so we require the updated weekly event probability to satisfy $$1 - \prod_{i=1}^7 (1 - kp_i) = 0.30.$$  This leads to a degree-$7$ polynomial in $k$, the approximate unique real solution of which is around $k \approx 1.23$.  You would need a numeric method to solve this polynomial for general $p_i$; one approach is to employ Newton's method with initial guess $k_0 = 1$, or a more crude approach is a recursive bisection algorithm (i.e. secant method) with initial guesses $k_0 = 1$, $k_1 = 1/(\max_i p_i)$ in the case where the updated overall probability is strictly greater than the old overall probability, since we cannot have $k p_i > 1$.  In the case where the updated probability needs to be lower, then of course $k_1 = 0$ would be your initial guess for the second endpoint in your recursive bisection.

---

Newton's method would be applied as follows.  Suppose the desired overall probability is $p_T$.  Construct the polynomial $$f(k) = (1-p_T) - \prod_{i=1}^7 (1 - kp_i),$$ and compute its derivative with respect to $k$:  $$f'(k) = -\frac{d}{dk} \prod_{i=1}^7 (1 - kp_i) = - \prod_{i=1}^7 (1-kp_i) \sum_{k=1}^7 \frac{p_i}{1-kp_i}.$$  Then set up the recursion relation $$k_n = k_{n-1} - \frac{f(k_{n-1})}{f'(k_{n-1})},$$ with the initial guess $k_0 = 1$.  Compute successive iterates $k_1, k_2, \ldots$, the limit of which should converge to the unique real root, given that none of the $p_i$ is equal to $1$.

---

Recursive bisection would work as follows.  As in Newton's method above, construct $f$.  Then for *two* initial guesses $k_0, k_1$, compute the midpoint $k_2 = (k_0 + k_1)/2$ and the values $$\left\{f(k_0), f(k_1), f(k_2)\right\}.$$  Compare the sign of $f(k_2)$ with the previous two values $f(k_0), f(k_1)$:  for instance, if $f(k_2)$ has the opposite sign of $f(k_1)$, then the next guess $k_3$ is the midpoint of $k_1$ and $k_2$.  Formally, $$k_{n+1} = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}(k_n + k_{n-1}), & s(f(k_n)) \ne s(f(k_{n-1})) \\ \frac{1}{2}(k_n + k_{n-2}), & s(f(k_n)) \ne s(f(k_{n-2})) \end{cases}$$ where $$s(x) = \begin{cases}1, & x > 0 \\ 0, & x = 0 \\ -1, & x < 0 \end{cases}$$ is the sign function.  The idea is to always choose the next guess for $k$ in such a way that guarantees the root is located somewhere between any two successive iterates.  Convergence is slower than with Newton's method but does not require computing derivatives.

Comment: Thanks very much for this - you were right to presume I meant proportionally. Can you give a bit more information on how the secant method might look - presumably the second equation would need rearranging for $k$, but I'm still not totally clear on how to implement this into code. Also in the real data, i is {1, 2, ... 52} - is the secant method still advisable in that case? Thanks again

Comment: @jayb I have amended my answer with the computational details of numerical approximation methods.  However, you may find the stability of implementation to be potentially problematic if the polynomial degree is very high, especially with Newton's method, and/or if the $p_i$ are very close to $0$ or $1$.